# link, input and button style consistency

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, hyperlink

I was wondering what resources exist for the consistent styling between buttons, inputs and links.
I am aware of [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/), however this appears to be quite a heavyweight solution. Is there anything that could assist me with this? tutorials, generators, plugins etc?

Comment: jQuery UI is pretty good. If you want a even lighter one, I think you may want to style by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) styles